# Fetch song details from third party app iOS

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I want to fetch the song details which is being played by a third party application like sound cloud, youtube, ganna etc. I know how to get song details if song is played by Music app of iOS. Please tell me if there is any way of accessing this information.

Thanks